# How do I configure my Derby.js application to use the LESS CSS engine?

Tags: javascript, node.js, less, derbyjs

According to the Derby blog and [this pull request](https://github.com/codeparty/derby/pull/33), Derby.js has supported the LESS engine since version 0.3.1.  However, I can't figure out where I'm supposed to set the configuration option to switch it from Stylus in my code.  I feel like it needs to happen with a `derby.use` call in my `lib/server/index.js` file, but there's nothing about it listed in the documentation that I've seen other than that it is possible.

I'd just use Stylus, but I'm trying to Columnal, which doesn't compile in Stylus. How can I configure the application to use LESS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no configuration option to set, it's all transparent. Just start using `.less` files in your `styles` directory.